# Inside Salesforce : Video Interviewing

Tags: apex, visualforce, content

I'm currently working developing a HR application. I’d like to be able to include video interviewing right inside of Salesforce.  Any thoughts on how to do so?

My thought would be while on a contact record the user presses the Video Interview button.  A new window appears with the video component.  The candidate connects, they conduct the interview and then the recorded interview is accessible for future review on the contact profile.

Thoughts on how we could create something like this?

Might be some JS framework (which I can use in Visualforce) that can allow me to record video, and then I upload the same either into Content or external storage like Amazon S3 etc ..

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this today would be some sort of Flash plugin. The reason I say "today", is because there are some very interesting developments on the HTML5 front around the [getUserMedia](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) API but they aren't widely implemented yet in browsers.

I'd look at using the Flex toolkit to build something and look to migrate to HTML5 getUserMedia when it's more of a browser standard. Storing it on S3 seems like a logical choice too.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. Sounds like FLASH is ideal option as of now. However will explore on HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're considering building this yourself, but there's an easier way. Video interviewing platform [Wowzer](http://wowzer.com) offers [integration with Salesforce.com](http://explore.wowzer.com/fall-2012-release) so you can invite and see candidate invitation status and responses from within your Salesforce interface. You'll probably want to use the Wowzer site itself to create the interviews since the creation UI is best there, but once your interviews are created you can do the inviting and reviewing from within Salesforce.

I encourage you to get a demo from the team and consider the integration option of a fully-featured option over building and maintaining your own one-off fix.

Comment: Interesting product.  Full disclosure:  it looks like  you are affiliated with Wowser.

Comment: Thanks Angela for this input. The point is to request interview for contact records in Salesforce and have theri inteview accessible from Salesforce (ie transparent to end users use the salesforce system). Not sure upto how much level of integration will be possible with Wowszer. However will explore more once I get started. Thank you Peter for the Full Disclosure :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider looking at OpenTok API - I've used it in a web app that I built (not on Salesforce though) as well as in one mobile app.

You should be able to do this form within a VisualForce page without any major issue.

On a separate note, since Salesforce acquired DimDim a while back, we've seen numerous improvements in Chatter including chat and presence. I won't be surprised if audio and video calls are definitely on the Salesforce Chatter roadmap in the near future.

Having said that, I'm not recommending you wait for Salesforce to roll out this feature :) Instead, go try OpenTok if that fits the bill for you.

Comment: Ok thanks Gaurav. That's good point. Will explore OpenTok too and seek your help (if required any).